# Download new Git branches to local Git repository

Tags: git, github

I set up a local Git repository that then I uploaded to GitHub.com as a repo to my account. If someone commits to it via the online interface (because it can't be done otherwise if my Git repo is local, on my PC - at least as far as I know), then how can I add the commits and branches of the given person to the local Git repo?

Maybe is there a command in Git Bash to add that info to the local repo?

Comment: `git pull`? I think you need to read up on git a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no one will be able to commit to your GitHub repository unless they have your credentials.

If they *do* have your credentials and make a commit you can download that commit to your local copy of the repository with:

```
git pull
```

Comment: Then why I was able to fork a project accidentally?

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt When you forked your project you created your own copy of that repo. So, when you commit and push you are altering your own copy, not the original copy that your forked from.

Comment: Thanks! So forks are absolutely allowed and free to own and modify, but they are not considered branches of the master repo.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt Correct, forks create a whole new copy of the repo, not a branch off the original repo that was forked from.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt: you're really confusing a lot of git concepts. Please read a git tutorial.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm in the middle of it, actually. But it's clearer now; also I wouldn't have written out this question if I wouldn't have thought it might be beneficial for other users.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand github. No one but you can push changes to your repository on your account. What happens when someone else changes something on the website is that they automatically create a fork, and a pull request, which is up to you to accept or don't.

The rest is normal git usage: to get changes done from a remote repository, do `git push` or `git fetch`, depending on whether you want to merge or not.

Really, I can't give you a full introduction to git here; read a git tutorial or do the github tutorials!

Comment: I don't need a full introduction of course, it was just a technical question coming to my mind while reading the tutorials.

Comment: @Marcus Don't you mean `pull` rather than `push`?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: no, "push changes to smth." in the sense of "changing that repository's state".